# Query from Latest Table Partition Wildcard in BigQuery

Tags: wildcard, google-bigquery

I have dataset called sample and table_201606, table_201607, until table_201710. Then things i want to accomplish is to get data from the latest TABLE SUFFIX, which is table_201710. Below is My Query:

```
     WITH max_table_time AS(
        SELECT
            TIMESTAMP_ADD(MAX(time), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS max_time,
            FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m", DATE(MAX(time))) AS par
        FROM
            `sample.table_*`
    ),


    xyz as(
        SELECT id, sum(total_a) as total_b, sum(total_c) as sum_total
        FROM `sample.table_*`
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = (SELECT par from play_partitions) 
        GROUP BY video_id
    )

    SELECT * FROM xyz
```

Somehow, the query above, scanning through all the table ( from table_201606 until table_201710) but the result is fine ( data in table_201710 ).

But, the result is different when i try this:

```
WITH max_table_time AS(
        SELECT
            TIMESTAMP_ADD(MAX(time), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS max_time,
            FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m", DATE(MAX(time))) AS par
        FROM
            `sample.table_*`
    ),


    xyz as(
        SELECT id, sum(total_a) as total_b, sum(total_c) as sum_total
        FROM `sample.table_*`
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '201710' 
        GROUP BY video_id
    )

    SELECT * FROM xyz
```

The Query above, just scanned table_201710 and resulting data which lies in table_201710. Different from the first query, that scan through all table but result the right data which lies in table_201710.

How could i say the first query scanned all table ? because when i perform the first query, the BigQuery Console just say i use 10 GB data rather than the second query that just use 200 MB data processed on the process.

I wonder why, is there someone could explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Just carefully read the wildcard table in BigQuery and found these sentences:

> Using _TABLE_SUFFIX can greatly reduce the number of bytes scanned, which reduces the cost of running your queries.
>   Filters on _TABLE_SUFFIX that include subqueries cannot be used to limit the number of tables scanned for a wildcard table. For example, the following query does not limit the tables scanned for the wildcard table bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod19*

I'm not doing RTFM before doing those queries. :D