# Bigquery charges for tables filtered out using _TABLE_SUFFIX?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am basically doing the following.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`
WITH data as (...)
SELECT *
FROM `dataset.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
(SELECT MAX(table_name) FROM `dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`)
AND 
CONCAT("events_",format_date("%Y%m%d", current_date('UTC')))
```

This pattern (`_TABLE_SUFFIX ...`) is taken from the OFFICIAL documentation of BQ.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables?authuser=0#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix

Everything is working. The caveat is that BQ charges for THE WHOLE `dataset.*` seemingly **without** filtering those `partitioned tables` inside the dataset.

This pattern is taken from the OFFICIAL documentation of BQ.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables?authuser=0#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix

Comment: Do  [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131624/query-from-latest-table-partition-wildcard-in-bigquery) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983962/) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew This is good, thank you. However, there is no one answer how to do that. The table is automatically created (sharded? partitioned?) by a native Google link between GA4 and BQ. It's a common pattern in scheduled queries to query only the latest data. How do people do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate your requirements so that I can understand what you are trying to do?